# ThunderboltEx 4 and docking station stops working on USB 2.0 after installing SSD card

Tags: windows, usb, bios

Last year, I built a gaming PC. As I am also working in home office with my company notebook, I wanted everything connected to a docking station, so I just need to switch the USB-C cable between the two devices.

I bought the [ThunderboltEx 4 card](https://www.asus.com/motherboards-components/motherboards/accessories/thunderboltex-4/) from ASUS, connected it via display port with my graphics card, activated ThunderboltEx 4 in the BIOS settings and everything worked like charm.

Until recently. I added a new SSD card to my gaming PC, turned it on, monitors came online
but nothing else.

It seems to my that suddenly the USB 2.0 connection from the ThunderboltEx 4 and my mainboard stopped working and I can’t get it running again.

I tried another USB 2.0 device with the same USB 2.0 headers and it works so I thought: Maybe it is the cable, so I bought another USB 2.0 header cable same result.

The monitors are working, the peripherals not. No mouse, no keyboard, no LAN, no headphones.

What could be going wrong with this setup?